# Busqueda sql por cualquier campo

Tags: sql-server

Como podria consultar en una tabla con cualquiera de sus campos ? algo mas o menos asi:

```
declare @variable varchar(50)
set @variable = 'Proveedor'

select * from proveedor where @variable like '%va%'
```

Aunque tenia esa idea, pero no filtra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes armar la consulta como una cadena y luego ejecutarla con el sp `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @campo varchar(10) = 'proveedor';

declare @sql varchar(1000) = 
           CONCAT('select * from proveedor where ',@campo, ' like %va%');

sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que se ejecute sql dinámico, hay que tener bien atado, que no podemos permitir inyección sql, porque si directamente, dejamos al cliente que pueda suministrar información directa al motor a través de texto, estamos expuestos.

Suponiendo que esta parte ya la tengas solucionada.

```
create table dbo.Proveedor (id int, valor varchar(10), proveedor nvarchar(100), fecha date, valor2 char(6), nums decimal(4,2));
go
Insert into dbo.Proveedor (id, valor, proveedor, fecha, valor2, nums)
values
(1,'val1','valiente','20190101','valuar',4.2),
(1,'owke','aaaaaaaa','20190101','aaaaaa',5.2);
go
```

El escenario que planteas con diversas columnas de diversos tipos.

Uno de los parámetros a tener en cuenta, es el tipo de columna al que vas a consultar, y en función del tipo, entregarle la query con apóstrofes, o sin ellos, o con un igual, o con un like. A tú criterio según la información a conseguir.

Para esto, es factible consultar a la vista del sistema Information_schema sobre el tipo de columnas de nuestra tabla y montar la query dinámica con este resultado.

```
DECLARE @variable NVARCHAR(128);
SET @variable = 'PROVEEDOR'
DECLARE @CONTENIDO NVARCHAR(100) = 'VA';

DECLARE @TYPE NVARCHAR(128) = 
(
    select DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Proveedor' 
    and COLUMN_NAME = @variable
);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Proveedor 
    WHERE '+@variable + 
    case @type 
-- (No están definidos todos los tipos, solamente los más comunes)
        when 'bit' then ' = '
        when 'date' then ' = ''' -- se doblan los apóstrofes
        when 'datetime' then ' = '''
        when 'decimal' then ' = '
        when 'int' then ' = '
        when 'money' then ' = '
        when 'nchar' then ' LIKE ''%'
        when 'numeric' then ' = '
        when 'nvarchar' then ' LIKE ''%'
        when 'smallint' then ' = '
        when 'smallmoney' then ' = '
        when 'time' then ' = '''
        when 'tinyint' then ' = '
        when 'uniqueidentifier' then ' = '''
        when 'varchar' then ' LIKE ''%' 
        when 'char' then ' LIKE ''%' 
    END
    + @CONTENIDO + 
    Case @type 
        when 'bit' then ';'
        when 'date' then ''';'
        when 'datetime' then ''';'
        when 'decimal' then ';'
        when 'int' then ';'
        when 'money' then ';'
        when 'nchar' then '%'';'
        when 'numeric' then ';'
        when 'nvarchar' then '%'';'
        when 'smallint' then ';'
        when 'smallmoney' then ';'
        when 'time' then ''';'
        when 'tinyint' then ';'
        when 'uniqueidentifier' then ''';'
        when 'varchar' then '%'';'
        when 'char' then '%'';' 
    END 

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Si observas la query, primero se busca el tipo de columna y en función del tipo que corresponda a la tabla proveedores, se establece el where. Si la columna es varchar el filtro es like '%xx%' donde xx está suministrado por una variable, pero si la columna es decimal el filtro será = xx

[image: Resultado]

Si yo busco por otra columna, por ejemplo nums y le paso un valor decimal

```
DECLARE @variable NVARCHAR(128);
SET @variable = 'nums'
DECLARE @CONTENIDO NVARCHAR(100) = '5.2';

DECLARE @TYPE NVARCHAR(128) = 
(
    select DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Proveedor' 
    and COLUMN_NAME = @variable
);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Proveedor 
    WHERE '+@variable + 
    case @type 
        when 'bit' then ' = '
        when 'date' then ' = ''' -- se doblan los apóstrofes
        when 'datetime' then ' = '''
        when 'decimal' then ' = '
        when 'int' then ' = '
        when 'money' then ' = '
        when 'nchar' then ' LIKE ''%'
        when 'numeric' then ' = '
        when 'nvarchar' then ' LIKE ''%'
        when 'smallint' then ' = '
        when 'smallmoney' then ' = '
        when 'time' then ' = '''
        when 'tinyint' then ' = '
        when 'uniqueidentifier' then ' = '''
        when 'varchar' then ' LIKE ''%' 
        when 'char' then ' LIKE ''%' 
    END
    + @CONTENIDO + 
    Case @type 
        when 'bit' then ';'
        when 'date' then ''';'
        when 'datetime' then ''';'
        when 'decimal' then ';'
        when 'int' then ';'
        when 'money' then ';'
        when 'nchar' then '%'';'
        when 'numeric' then ';'
        when 'nvarchar' then '%'';'
        when 'smallint' then ';'
        when 'smallmoney' then ';'
        when 'time' then ''';'
        when 'tinyint' then ';'
        when 'uniqueidentifier' then ''';'
        when 'varchar' then '%'';'
        when 'char' then '%'';' 
    END 

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

[image: Salida]

[exec sp_executeSql](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)